# PayUMoney in Android WebView showing blank screen

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to integrate my Android app with PayUMoney.

If I don't put in -

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

its opening in the browser and working fine. But if I do, the WebView shows a loading sort of activity and then the whole thing goes blank.

And also if I create some error in the data, the error page from PayUMoney loads in the WebView without any problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to PayUMoney Tech Support. I had to add -

```
myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

now it is working.

Comment: this is not working for me, do you have any other solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your URL with this and try again.

```
String PAYMENT_URL = "https://test.payu.in/_payment";
```